# parameter data is missing in ajax html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ajax html link does not contain parameter data to be send to another controller.

View

```
       @Ajax.ActionLink(((string)item.street + ' ' + (string)item.city ), "showDetails","RentOutSpace", new { spaceId = @item.spaceId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" } )
```

when i view page source it is shown as below

```
      <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" href="/RentOutSpace/showDetails">12 Rawalpindi</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model does not contain data.Syntax for ajax link is correct but model data was null. This is  the reason that parameter data was missing.

Query did not return data.By modifying the query i have successfully send parameter data to controller via ajax action link.